# How to override @override method from activity into another class

Tags: java, android

Hi let's say I have an activity

```
class AcitivityA {


    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Do something
    }


}
```

And I have a class name

```
class myClass {


    private Activity current_activity;


    myClass(Activity activity) {
        current_activity = activity;
    }
}
```

So my question is, is there a way i can override onConfigurationChanged and put it into my class myClass?

So my goal is that I want to detect if the orientation is change

But I want it to be inside the class myClass

Comment: Extend 'myClass' with 'AcitivityA'

Comment: Have your `ActivityA` instance call a method on your `myClass` instance from an `onConfigurationChanged()` method in `ActivityA`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Listener for that.

```
public interface OnChange() {
  void changed();
}

public class ListenerHolder {
    public static OnChange onChange = new OnChange( ... );
}

MyClass mClass = new MyClass();

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    ListenerHolder.onChange.changed();
}
```

Take care that the interface should be static somewhere else then the own activity, else it may be destroyed with the activity.

But there are a few better ways solving that. BroadcastReceivers, Deeplinking, Extending, LiveData (Livecycle-aware), RxJava Subjects, ...

It's a bad design pattern to hook into view events outside a class which is not used for that.

Take a look at [Android Architecture Components](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components)  which uses a Mvvm Pattern including ViewModels and LiveData to survive configuration changes.

If you'r new to Android i highly recommend you to take a look at https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/index.html for a proper design of your app. You may also start using Kotlin because it will be the maintained language in future for android.

Comment: is there a way that no need to add interface sir?
because my activity is dynamic since it will be the current active activity
by the way the class in a service

Comment: Yes, use a proper design pattern. AAC/MVVM is designed to be lifecycle aware (and also survive onconfigurationchange)